# Amplitude vs. Amplitude Spectrum?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I feel like I keep getting confused about amplitudes when talking about signal processing. Maybe someone can help clear my confusion. Let's say I have a simple sinusoid:

$f(t)=A \sin(\omega_0 t)$.

The amplitude of this sinusoid is $A$ (which seems very obvious). But if I do a Fourier transform, $F(\omega)$ of $f(t)$ and then plot $|F(\omega) | $, I get a spike at $\omega_0$ and zeros elsewhere. $|F(\omega)|$ is called the "amplitude spectrum".

Does the amplitude spectrum have any relation to the amplitude, $A$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $F(\omega)=A\delta(\omega=\omega_0)$, so in some generalized sense magnitude of $F(\omega_0)$ is A.

Comment: The integral of the Fourier transform in frequency space would give you the amplitude A. However, the amplitude spectrum refers more specifically to the frequencies of interest ($\omega_0$ in this example) and the corresponding amplitude of each frequency.